# Xcode 5.1.1 behaving oddly

Tags: ios, xcode, ide, xcode5

My Xcode 5.1.1. is behaving very oddly today, to give an example : I have 2 projects open, one of the projects I could click and drag new assets to my navigator. on the other, its not allowing me to bring anything in, if I try to go in the bottom of the navigator to "Add files", no file I select gets actually brought in to the project.. Does anyone know why this is going on?

**EDIT**

I have also tried adding manually thru finder, but no luck, even after restart...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the search bar at the bottom of the navigator is blank. If you are currently filtering anything, you won't be able to drag and drop files into the navigator and any files added by using "Add Files" will be filtered out if their filenames do not contain the text in the search bar.